# SSIS Script component to process data in a loop based on a group

Tags: ssis

Summary: I need to process a group of sorted rows and based on the output, need to go back to row 1 and set a value for that. Whole of input has many different groups(class data)- so this has to be repeated for each group.

Detailed information with example:

Input has 10 rows- first 5 belong to class A and second 5 belong to class B and so on. Data is sorted in ascending timestamp for each class.

The first and last row of each class will always belong to Category Q and remaining within will have other categories.

Customer id's are available for all records except the Q category record.
The Q category customer id will be same for a specific class. Ex: Row 1,5(class A) - c1 and row 6,10 will be c5.

Rowid       Class        Category         Customer

1         classA            Q
2         classA            R                c1
3         classA            S                c1
4         classA            T                c2
5         classA            Q
6         ClassB            Q
7         ClassB            T               c3
8         ClassB            R               c4
9         ClassB          S100              c5
10        ClassB            Q

There is a specific logic used to determine Q category customer id based on the non Q category customer id's. This will only be known as I process all the records in each class. Once I know this, I need to go back to the first record and set the customer id and also set the same for the last record for each class.

I have created a script component transformation, where I read each row.
I track if the class has changed or not. with in the same class data, I used variables to implement the logic to get the customer id of the Q category record.

I write this to the output- last record for a given class.

Outside of script component, I applied another sort to reverse sort the data.
Then applied another script component where I can simply set the customer id of say Rowid 1 based on the customerid of Rowid 5 as the data is reverse sorted.

This works fine, but I want to complete this in a single script component.

Does "ProcessInputRow" method help me read only a few records in a loop and process them to find the Q customer id? Then I can output the value and proceed again with next class of data.

Is there any other way to accomplish, where I have to go back to the top record to set the customer id?

[image: Group processing image]

Final Result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind posting an image of the expected output, when you're done with all the processing?

Comment: Hi Mark, the expected output contains the customer id for the records 1,5,6,10- these are the records with category Q. As I cannot show the real data, I made up the above scenario.                                                                                                                                                                                                            Rowid Class Category Customer
1 classA Q c1
2 classA R c1
3 classA S c1
4 classA T c2
5 classA Q c1
6 ClassB Q c4
7 ClassB T c3
8 ClassB R c4
9 ClassB S100 c5
10 ClassB Q c4

Comment: Hi Kal, I have added an image of the expected results.  Please make sure I have that right.  Answering this question will be a trick w/o knowing the logic to get the correct customer within a class.  However, I would recommend dropping the results into a staging table and performing the update in SQL, which will be an easier place to work with sets.  If you can share some more logic, I'll provide an example of how that could be done.

Comment: Hi Mark,

The logic implementation is- if there is a category with 'S100' anywhere for a given class then pick the last customer just before the Q category record as the Q category customer else pick the first customer after the top Q record for a given class as the Q category customer record.I have implemented this, but want to fine tune. Can this be done in single piece of c# code where I can buffer all records for a given class, get the logic and process from begining again for same class. In the image above, for class B - Q cust will be c5. - Kal

Answer (score 0):

You would have to post some code to start with for refactoring help on the C# you are using in SSIS.

In the meanwhile, this is how I would approach the problem in SQL as a set based operation.  Imagine that the temp table is some permanent staging table that you would insert the data into with SSIS:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #input;
CREATE TABLE #input
  (
     rowid      INT,
     className  VARCHAR(20),
     ClassCode  VARCHAR(10),
     customerid VARCHAR(20)
  );

INSERT INTO #input(rowid, className, ClassCode, customerid)
Values
(1 ,'classA' ,'Q' , NULL)
, (2 ,'classA' ,'R' , 'c1')
, (3 ,'classA' ,'S' , 'c1')
, (4 ,'classA' ,'T' , 'c2')
, (5 ,'classA' ,'Q' , NULL)
, (6 ,'ClassB' ,'Q' , NULL)
, (7 ,'ClassB' ,'T' , 'c3')
, (8 ,'ClassB' ,'R' , 'c4')
, (9 ,'ClassB' ,'S100', 'c5')
, (10, 'ClassB', 'Q', NULL);


; WITH S100_Classes
     AS (SELECT className
                , classcode
                , lag(customerid, 1)
                    OVER (
                      partition BY className
                      ORDER BY rowid) AS customerid
         FROM   #input i
         WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM   #input t
                        WHERE  i.className = t.className
                               AND t.ClassCode = 'S100')),
     S100
     AS (SELECT className
                , customerid
         FROM   S100_Classes
         WHERE  ClassCode = 'S100'),
     other_Classes
     AS (SELECT TOP (1) className
                        , customerid
         FROM   #input i
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   #input t
                            WHERE  i.className = t.className
                                   AND t.ClassCode = 'S100')
                AND customerid IS NOT NULL
         ORDER  BY rowid)
SELECT i.rowid
       , i.className
       , i.ClassCode
       , COALESCE(i.customerid, s.customerid, o.customerid) AS Customerid
FROM   #input i
       LEFT JOIN S100 s
              ON i.className = s.className
       LEFT JOIN other_Classes o
              ON i.className = o.className
```